# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color

Tags: r, r-markdown, miktex

Just updated R to version 4.0.2 (from 3.6.3) and rmarkdown to v2.3 (from 1.13). But I face several problems when knitting to pdf. I used the following code in the yaml section of a new rmarkdown (pdf), leaving the rest of the contents unchanged, and I got the error of the title.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 9
    includes:
      in_header: greek.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    pandoc_args: [
                   "--variable", "geometry:paperwidth=8.27in",
                   "--variable", "geometry:paperheight=11.69in",
                   "--variable", "geometry:left=0.75in",
                   "--variable", "geometry:right=0.75in",
                   "--variable", "geometry:top=0.75in",
                   "--variable", "geometry:bottom=0.75in"
                 ]

---
```

greek.tex contents:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Segoe UI} 
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Πίνακας}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
```

I also noticed that html code like this, that I need when knitting to html

```
<div class="text-center">
```

now generate errors, like

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment text-center undefined.
```

Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2  htmltools_0.5.0 tools_4.0.2     yaml_2.2.1     
 [5] rmarkdown_2.3   knitr_1.29      xfun_0.16       digest_0.6.25  
 [9] packrat_0.5.0   rlang_0.4.7     evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: [This seems relevant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25664/conflict-between-options-of-packages) over the `color` option clash. I can knit a sweave doc if I remove the `color` options and add `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames, dvipsnames}{color}` before the `\documentclass`

Comment: @user20650 you should post that as an answer. It just solved a problem for me.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen; please go ahead -- your memory off this will be *a lot* fresher

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me recently. Output to tex, then add the following to the head of the document (before documentclass):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames, dvipsnames}{color}
```

Then compile. Thanks to @user20650 for the link!

Comment: can you help me out on my question rmakrdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749311/custom-table-for-rmarkdown-pdf)